# QGIS "invents" coordinate decimal places from imported PostGIS geom

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, coordinates

I have a PostGIS database with an geom-accurancy of 9 decimal places for X and 8 decimal places for Y.

Reading out the coordinates of an PostGIS-Polygon in PyQGIS shows:

```py
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect('spb', 'postgres', 'postgres', 'localhost', 5433)
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = f"""SELECT ST_AsText(geom)
          FROM geom
          WHERE id = 19695"""
cur.execute(sql)
cur.fetchone()

# Output:
('MULTIPOLYGON(((349749.532007553 5575769.14298604,349777.370999882 5575792.32299964,349792.406197559 5575794.8902163,...)',)
```

But when I import the polygon from PostGIS as a layer in QGIS, and read out its coordinates afterwards, I see that QGIS "invents" new decimal places, 17 for X and Y.

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5433", "spb", "postgres", "postgres")
uri.setDataSource ("public", "geom", "geom", "id = 19695")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri .uri(False), "geom", "postgres")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

lyr = iface.activeLayer()
features = lyr.getFeatures()
for f in features:
    f.geometry()

# Output
<QgsGeometry: MultiPolygon (((349749.53200755297439173 5575769.14298603963106871, 349777.37099988199770451 5575792.32299964036792517, 349792.40619755897205323 5575794.89021630026400089,...>
```

So what QGIS is doing here? How can I prevent that QGIS "invents" non existing decimal places?

Comment: It is not possible to express a decimal number 349749.532007553 as a floating point number. You can test that for example with https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter.

Comment: So `f.geometry()` returns a floating point number? How I can return a decimal number representation of the coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a PostGIS database, I create a new table and add as layer the sample in QGIS

```
CREATE TABLE to_delete AS
SELECT 1, ST_SetSrid(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((349749.532007553 5575769.14298604,349777.370999882 5575792.32299964,349792.406197559 5575794.8902163, 349749.532007553 5575769.14298604)))'), 3857) AS geom;
```

Due to comment feedback by @user30184

> It is not possible to express a decimal number 349749.532007553 as a floating point number.

You can check it's fine also in QGIS, it's just the representation when printing the `QGsGeometry` returned by your `f.geometry()` that mislead you.

You will see it's fine when inspecting points coordinates from your polygons in below sample

```py
# Explore coordinates infos precision
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = f.geometry()
    # print with the "wrong" precision
    print(geom)
    # if geom.type() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry and geom.isMultipart():
    # below if is a shorter equivalent of above test
    if geom.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.MultiPolygon:
        vertices_iterators_parts = [i.vertices() for i in geom.parts()]
        for vertices_iterator in vertices_iterators_parts:
            for point in vertices_iterator:
                x = point.x()
                y = point.y()
                # print with the "right" precision
                print(x, y)
```